# Anybody using SLDS Design Tokens in conjunction with React?

Tags: slds, design-tokens

The Salesforce Lightning Design System offers a set of [Design Tokens](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/design-tokens/) that are described as the "visual design atoms of the design system". The Lightning Component framework easily allows you to pull these design tokens into your Lightning Components. However, I'm currently developing an application based on React JS that attempts to adhere to SLDS styling. I can achieve much of this by loading the SLDS resource bundle into my application and creating React components that render SLDS conformant markup with SLDS CSS classes applied. What I'm not able to wrap my head around is how I would incorporate SLDS Design Tokens into a React-based application. Has anyone out there done this, or even tried this? I'd be interested in any suggestions here.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce recently released this [react component library for SLDS](https://github.com/salesforce/design-system-react).  I haven't had a chance to try it out yet, but it seems to be actively being worked on.

Comment: Awesome. Looking forward to giving this a try.